# What statistical tests to use?

Tags: regression, pearson-r, confirmatory-factor

My topic is on A Study of Budget Slack and the Influence of Budget Participation on Budget Slack. My research objectives are to study the relationship between budget participation, procedural fairness, distributive fairness, trust, goal commitment and manager's propensity to create slack, to investigate the relationship between budget participation on budget slack, to study the impacts of budgetary slack to companies' managerial performance and to determine the effectiveness of budget participation on managerial performance. I am using questionnaire of 7-point Likert Scale from 1- Strongly disagree to 7- Strongly agree for data collection. For budget participation, my questionnaire has 6 questions of Likert Scale type. Should I use mean or median to combine the 6 questions of budget participation into one item of one value for budget participation in SPSS? Budget participation is the independent variable. The mediating variables are procedural fairness, distributive fairness, trust, goal commitment. The dependent variable is budget slack. I would like to test the reliability of the data using Cronbach alpha. I would like to use Pearson correlation to study the relationship of budget participation, procedural fairness, distributive fairness, trust, goal commitment towards budget slack. I would like to use multiple regression for hypothesis testing. And I would like to use factor analysis to test the 6 factors which are budget participation, procedural fairness, distributive fairness, trust, goal commitment and manager's propensity to create slack. My sample size is 154 respondents. The target population is on managers from small and medium companies (SMEs). Am I on the right track for my statistical tests? Any suitable recommendations of statistical tests for my research? Thanks.﻿